# How to $match and then accumulate within $group stage in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

In one aggregation stage within my MongoDB view pipeline I am using `$group`. One of the things I'm doing within that `$group` stage is summing up an `openBalance`, like this:

```
  "openBalance": {
    "$sum": "$openBalance"
  },
```

This works.

However, I also need to get another value, that first matches to a condition, and *then* sums data. In other words, something like this:

```
  "customerResponsibleOpenBalance": {
    "$match": {
      "customerResponsible": true
    },
    "$sum": "$openBalance"
  },
```

However, I can't do this like this within a `$group` stage, because it results in this error:

> `customerResponsibleOpenBalance` must specify one accumulator.

So how would I go about doing this in a different way? Are `$facets` my only option here?

Comment: $group works on a set of documents. Why do you want to use `$match` ? Does it mean "any `customerResponsible` field set to true" ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. It means, look through the documents, and if the value for the field`customerResponsible` is set to true, include it in the `$sum` here.

Comment: You can use $sum with $cond expression. Something like `{"$sum":{"$cond":["$customerResponsible","$openBalance",0]}}` and  `{"$sum":{"$cond":["$customerResponsible",0, "$openBalance"]}}`

Comment: Ah, okay, This looks like the right way to go for what I want to accomplish.

Comment: "customerResponsibleOpenBalance": {
        "$sum": {"$cond":["$customerResponsible","$openBalance", 0] }
      },

Answer (score 1):

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#accumulator-operator) works on a set of documents so you can only use accumulators to get a result. To get `$sum` conditionally you can use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator inside of it, and add `0` if there's no match:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        balanceForTrue: { $sum: { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$customerResponsible", true ] }, then: "$balance", else: 0  } } },
        balanceForFalse: { $sum: { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$customerResponsible", false ] }, then: "$balance", else: 0  } } }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, to clarify, I have "openBalance" already. That's working. What I ALSO want is to, on the fly, generate a value for a new field, that sums up the openBalance, just like the first one, but does so ONLY for those documents for which "customerResponsible" is set to true. I also want a third value, giving me the $sum of "openBalance" for where "customerResponsible" is set to false. So, I have openBalance. That's working. Is there a way, within this $group stage, that I could also generate those other two values I need?

Comment: Hi mickl can you please let me know why this doesn't work... I am doing `$filter` to 3 nested level... https://mongoplayground.net/p/U_ohSoTZ6Rg... I want only `nokia` element from 3rd array and `6666` from second... If you want then I can ask a question as well... But please help to solve this first

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I guess you should since it has nothing to do with this question, I'll try to take a look

Comment: Yes it has nothing with this question but most of the time I see you doing amazing things with aggregation on stack... So for notify you I commented here... Thanks for the help

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet cool, thanks, please open new question and I'll try to fix that, it's hard to explain that in comments